# Imagem do banco de dados em reportviewer

Tags: c#, reportviewer

Olá, estou com o seguinte problema: tenho uma tabela de `Paciente` e nela tem um campo `Foto`, que é uma `string` com o caminho dessa foto. Preciso gerar um relatório com os dados do paciente selecionado e nesse relatório deve conter do mesmo. Como fazer isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defina a propriedade `EnableExternalImages` para `true`:

```
this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.EnableExternalImages = true;
```

E utilize um caminho absoluto e no seguinte formato:

```
string caminho = "file:////D:\UmCaminho\UmaImagem.JPG";
```